# Is it possible to create an instrument on the amount of beds sold within the real-estate market

Tags: futures, derivatives, modern-portfolio-theory, finance-mathematics, real-estate

I have been doing some research on the PBSA (purpose-built student accommodation) market around the globe. The market is growing year on year there is an index on this market the [cbre](https://www.cbre.co.uk/research-and-reports/United-Kingdom-Student-Accommodation-Index-2018).

What instrument would we use to trade on the amount of beds on the market? synthetics won’t work I’m not looking for exchange income or total return swap. I don’t think forwards/futures will work

The purpose of this instrument will need to allow investors trade Beds as an underlying asset as that’s how the market operates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, if you can find a bank willing to create this and sell it to you.

Otherwise, barring another market participant, your best bet is to try to convince the index owner to license it to an ETF provider for retail distribution.